# How to convert units of KDE into physical units

Tags: kernel-smoothing, histogram

I have a sample of people's heights. If I histogram it, I would usually divide by the bin width, so that my result becomes independent of my bin width, and I would label the axis something like (number of observations per unit height). If I do a KDE instead, it comes as a normalised distribution. To get that into physical units, do I simply multiply by the number of samples that I have?

[image]

```
import requests # pip install requests for easy http request for CSV data
import csv

# Get sample data:
url = "http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Galton.txt"
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(url)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

data_iter = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter='\t')
data = [data for data in data_iter]

# Organise it:
height = np.zeros((len(data)-1,1))
for i in np.arange(1,len(data)):
    height[i-1] = data[i][4]

# Plot it:
for binWidth in [1,2,5]:
    bins,edges = np.histogram(height,bins=np.arange(55,80,binWidth))
    plt.bar(edges[:-1]+0.5*np.mean(np.diff(edges)),bins/binWidth,alpha=0.5,label='binWidth=%g'%binWidth,width=binWidth)
plt.xlabel('Height (inches)'); plt.ylabel('dN/dH (Count/Inch)')

kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(height.flatten())
plt.plot(np.linspace(40,90,901),len(height)*kernel(np.linspace(40,90,901)),'k',label='KDE $\\times$ Nsamples')
plt.xlim(40,90);
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do. Both (normalized) KDE and a (normalized) histogram are approximations of the probability distribution of a random variable, however the former is discrete and the latter is continuous.

For a discrete i.i.d random variable, the expected number of observations that have a certain value is just $\langle n_i \rangle = n p_i$, since it is the expected value of a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

For a continuous i.i.d random variable, you achieve the same effect by scaling the probability density. The physical meaning is that, for any interval $[a,b]$ of the random variable $x$, the expected number of observations falling into that interval is $n\int_a^b\rho(x)dx$, which is just the fraction of observations falling into that interval times the number of observations, same as in the discrete case.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a convention for naming the y-axis? As in I did dN/dH -- as in dNumber/dHeight such that integrating over all H will leave you with the number of observations.

Comment: @James Sorry I don't know. I think as long as you are consistent in your work, many sensible naming conventions are good enough. Yours seems fine.